# My attempt at netcat in C++ won't get me replies from the server

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, http, port

I've made my attempt at netcat in a C++ program that uses sockets. It seems to be able to generate the socket, connect, and maybe send data fine but there seems to be an error I can't find. It doesn't properly return replies from the server. I'm able to *connect* to my HTTP server and scanme.nmap.org fine, but whenever I test it by sending a `HEAD / HTTP/1.1` (banner grab) it **doesn't show any response from the server**. Sense I have made the program so that if it has an error generating a socket, connecting, sending my input, it will alert me and terminate I know that it's having no issue doing these. So I know that **the program is working as it should, but there has to be either a problem with the way it sends data or with the way it handles replies. Interestingly, when connecting to my router I'm able to get a proper response which is the same `400 Bad Request` I get from netcat**

**EDIT: I FORGOT MY CODE. ADDING THAT IN RIGHT NOW**

**EDIT: THERE**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
        if (argv[1] == NULL) {
                cout << "\033[31mTARGET NOT SPECIFIED - TERMINATING...\033[0m\n";
                return -1;
        }
        if (argv[2] == NULL) {
                cout << "\033[31mPORT NOT SPECIFIED - TERMINATING...\033[0m\n";
                return -2;
        }

        string target = argv[1];
        int port = atoi(argv[2]);

        cout << "GENERATING SOCKET...\n";
        int chatter = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (chatter == -1) {
                cout << "\033[31mSOCKET GENERATION FAILURE - TERMINATING...\033[0m\n";
                return -3;
        }
        cout << "\033[32mSUCCESSFULLY GENERATED SOCKET\033[0m\n";

        struct sockaddr_in hint;
        hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
        hint.sin_port   = htons(port);
        inet_pton(AF_INET, target.c_str(), &hint.sin_addr);

        cout << "CONNECTING TO " << target << " AT PORT " << port << "...\n";
        int connection_status = connect(chatter, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));
        if (connection_status == -1) {
                cout << "\033[31mCONNECTION FAILURE - TERMINATING...\033[0m\n";
                return -4;
        }
        cout << "\033[32mCONNECTED TO HOST\033[0m\n";

        char buf[1024];
        string msg;
        while (true) {
                getline(cin, msg);
                int sendmsg = send(chatter, msg.c_str(), msg.size()+1, 0);
                if (sendmsg == -1) {                        
                        cout << "\033[31mCONSISTENT MESSAGE SENDING FAILURE - TERMINATING...\033[0m\n";
                        return -5;
                }
                memset(buf, 0, 1024);
                int byterecv = recv(chatter, buf, 1024, 0);
                cout << string(buf, byterecv) << "\r\n";
        }

        close(chatter);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `recv` is under no obligation to return all the data in a single call.

Comment: So would this mean that there could be a delay?

Comment: Yes.  The function also might also only return a partial message.  Check the return value and if it's negative, check `errno`.  Look at `select()` too.

Comment: Alright, I just made it so when `recv` returns -1 it alerts me. I ran my tests and that doesn't seem to be happening.

Comment: Don't you think that it would be more sensible to actually print out the return value?  This is the first thing you should do to debug simple problems.  It's probably returning 0.  You probably need to call `select`.

Comment: Alright I had to figure out how to to return errno and in case I'm doing it wrong, I'm including `errno.h` and am `cout`ing `strerror(errno)`. When testing it on my router, I was getting `Success`, when testing on scanme.nmap.org, it wasn't giving me anything just like how I'm not seeing any server replies.

Comment: ... `errno` is only set if the return value is -1.  You've already said the return value is not negative.  I told you to just print out the return value to find out what it actually is.  In case you are still confused, I am talking about doing `cout << byterecv << "\n";` after your call to `recv`.  I've suggested it may be zero, and I've suggested twice already that you look at the documentation for `select`.  This makes three times.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real netcat can read from socket and from stdin in parallel. Your program can read either from stdin or from the socket and both of these calls `getline()` and `recv()` are waiting of there are no data.

So your program probably:

1. `getline()` reads a line from stdin. The line contains something like "GET ... \n"
2. send the line to server but it is not complete http request because it is not ended by empty line so http server does not respond and waits for http headers.
3. Your program calls `recv()` and blocks forever.

You need to change the logic of your program. You can either use separate threads for reading from stdin and receiving data or you can use `select()` or `poll()` which provides waiting for an events on multiple file descriptors.

EDIT: additional clarification due to a question in comment

The HTTP request consists of

- request line
- request headers (0 headers are valid)
- request body (can be empty)

Request headers and request body are diveded by an empty line. The empty line is required even if the body is empty because server needs to know that there are no more headers.

Moreover the HTTP standard requires `<CR><LF>` at the and of line. Minimum valid HTTP request (no headers, empty body) is a request line followed by an empty line: `"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n"`

Comment: "send the line to server but it is not complete http request because it is not ended by empty line so http server does not respond and waits for http headers." should I append `\n` to my input messages then?

Comment: yes - see the updated answer - actually you should add `\r\n`.

Comment: I assume this is fine but just checking, will the request work fine if I append `\r\n` instead of `\r\n\r\n` except I make sure to hit enter again after sending my request? EDIT: Additional clarification: If I'm not wrong just doing that would still give the required `\r\n\r\n`, I know this seems kind of pointless but I want the program to be like netcat and not necessarily only for HTTP.

Comment: Sure, when you hit the enter again than the server receives an empty line. There are still a pitfall. Netcat and and your program just copy the input to a socket. Terminal input contains only `\n` at the end of  line but standard requires `\r\n`. Nevertheless all http server implementations I know are benevolent and accept \n only.